# translate raw MySQL into Doctrine 1.2

Tags: doctrine, doctrine-1.2

I'm having a heck of a time translating the following raw MySQL query, which has been tested and works very well, into doctrine 1.2:

```
SELECT
    r.name AS regionname,
    s.name AS statename
FROM
    job j
LEFT JOIN
    community c ON c.id = j.community_id
LEFT JOIN
    state s ON s.id = c.state_id
LEFT JOIN
    region r ON r.id = s.region_id
WHERE
    r.id = 1
```

This does not work:

```
$q = Doctrine_Query::create()  
    ->select('r.name AS regionname', 's.name AS statename')
    ->from('job j')
    ->leftJoin('community c ON c.id = j.community_id')
    ->leftJoin('state s ON s.id = c.state_id')
    ->leftJoin('region r ON r.id = s.region_id')
    ->where('r.id = 1')
    ->execute();
```

Here's my db structure, if it is useful:

```
job:
columns:
  id
  community_id
relations:
  community:  local_key: community_id, foreign_key: id, foreignAlias: Communitys

community:
columns:
  id
  state_id
relations: 
  state: local_key: state_id, foreign_key: id, foreignAlias: States

state:
columns:
  id
  name
  region_id
relations:
  region: local_key: region_id, foreign_key: id, foreignAlias: Regions

region:
columns:
  id
  name
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have noticed the same thing as well. Doing joins in Doctrine 1.2 is a little bit different from mysql. To do a join, you have to take advantage of the relationships that Doctrine creates in each component in your case the job class.

You can check the job's base class for these relationships I am talking about. In the setup method, they look like this for example for a community foreign key id in the job table:

```
  $this->hasOne('community as Communitys', array(
         'local' => 'community_id',
         'foreign' => 'id'));
```

Back to your question, to do a join you have to reference the alias of the table where the foreign key belongs to. For example if you want to join on the community table with the alias Community:

```
->leftJoin('j.Community')
```

instead of

```
community c ON c.id = j.community_id
```

Notice that I didn't say join on id because in Doctrine 1.2 that is implied already. You can however choose to join on something else.

Likewise if tables you have previously joined to need to be joined to other tables they have foreign keys to you have to

1.use their alias in the current queryand 
 2.reference the component as stated in THEIR base class as well.

So you said that you want to join community to states in the current query the way you should do it is

```
// join job and community first
->from('job j')
->leftJoin('j.Community c')
// join community to state since they are the ones that are related
->leftjoin('c.States s')
```

From here I hope you can see the pattern. At the end of the day if you look at it the idea of joining is still the same with raw sql, the only difference is the syntax:

SQL syntax:

```
LEFT JOIN
    community c ON c.id = j.community_id
```

DQL syntax:

```
->leftJoin('j.Community c')
```

Anyway to answer your question, here is how the join should somewhat be done:

```
$q = Doctrine_Query::create()  
    ->select('*')
    ->from('job j')
    ->leftJoin('j.Community c')
    ->leftJoin('c.State s')
    ->leftJoin('s.Region r')
    ->where('r.id = 1')
    ->execute();
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer.  Unfortunately, it isn't working.  I too tried to key off of the foreign alias, but it gets hung up on those.  This is the error I'm getting when I try to use them: "Unknown relation alias Communitys"  And I get those errors whenever I try any of them.  I'll check what they are in the setup method and repost.  Thanks again.

Comment: ...and that does appear to be the problem.  There is no 'community as Communitys' statement, just 'Community, array('.  Which perplexes me a bit, because my schema does state it as foreign alias.  But my schema does not identify it as a one-to-one relationship.  Is that the problem?

Comment: update: I changed the base class to include the "as" clause (I know this is bad form, and I will change it in the schema if it ultimately corrects the problem) and it did fix the problem for the "Community" relationship, however, it now gets hung up on the "States" clause, giving me an error saying that the job has to relate to the state... which it doesn't in my schema... the community relates to the state.  Any idea for a solution?

Comment: update 2: fyi, after I updated my base classes to include the "as" clause, it breaks all previous queries in my app that were keying on "community", so it doesn't look like updating the relationships to a one-to-one is the solution.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I just saw this now and we might have a difference in the timezones. Can you post your Job base class here?

Comment: My turn to apologize, and thank you for taking the time to troubleshoot my problem.  I have posted my base class in the original question.  It has been truncated so if you notice some discrepancies, it's probably due to that.  Thanks again.

Comment: You're lucky I am awake at 4am studying and working. Updated my answer ;)

Comment: I meant to thank you before... thanks, Juene!  Got it working with your persistent help.